# A formal term/phrase for "geeking out"?

Tags: synonyms, formality, phrase-requests, prepositional-phrases

I'm trying to convey in an essay that I often find a piece of information (an esoteric mathematical equation, to be exact) and get really excited. Is the following sentence not appropriate for a Statement of Purpose?

> Or better yet, I’m probably geeking out about a new equation I found and boring everyone around me telling them about it!

I'd really appreciate if anyone could help formalize this! Thanks.

Comment: *Overexcited*, perhaps?

Comment: *Thrilled*, perhaps?